# Making list for large FASTA data

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm looking for the script which could load fasta.txt consisted of several large FASTA sequences sorting it in accordance to its headers (>FASTA) and sequence instanses on the separate lists

Below you can find the code which do such task

```
def main(FASTA):


    in_file=open(FASTA,'r')
    dir,file=os.path.split(FASTA)
    temp = os.path.join(dir,output)
    out_file=open(temp,'w')

    data=''
    name_list=[]
    seq_list=[]

    for line in in_file:

        line=line.strip()
        for i in line:
            if i=='>':
                name_list.append(line)
                if data:
                    seq_list.append(data)
                    data=''
                break
            else:
                line=line.upper()
        if all([k==k.upper() for k in line]):
            data=data+line

    #print seq_list[0] #TEST
```

How its possible to simplify such code ? Briefly it should load each sequence string to the data list ignoring >FASTA titles and then complile all data instances to the seq list consisted of each sequence as the separate list element. Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at Biopython. It has a SeqIO module that enables you to easily parse Fasta files, among others.

You can see the documentation here: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you could do this way, given a fasta file like this :

```
!cat foo.fst 
>AAAAA
ATCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTAGGCTAGCGAATCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTAGGCTAGCGAATCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTA
>CCCCCC
CGGAGCTAGGCTAGCGAATCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTAGCGGAGCTAGGCTAGCGAATCGATCG
>BBBBBB
TCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTAGCGGAGCTAGGCTAGCGAATCGATCGATCGATTCGATCGGAGCTAGCGGAGCTAGGCTAG
```

NB : You need [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page)

```
import numpy as np
from Bio import SeqIO

allseq = []
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("foo.fst","fasta"):
    allseq.append(seq_record)

for s in allseq:
    print s.name
# AAAAA
# CCCCCC
# BBBBBB


allseq2 = np.array(allseq)
idsort = np.argsort([i.name for i in allseq])

my_sequences = allseq2[idsort]
for s in my_sequences:
    print s.name
# AAAAA
# BBBBBB
# CCCCCC
```

Then you can access to your sequences sorted by their name with s.seq instead of s.name

Hope this helps. 
But if it doesn't answer your question, please, try to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! But how to obtain list of sequences only using biopython? For example seq=[s.seq for s in allseq] produce list with some extra unusefull data like Seq('CTTATTCCCCACGCAAACGCGTCCAGCGCAATTAAATCGCAGGTGCAAAAACAG...CTA', SingleLetterAlphabet()), Seq('GATCGCGGCTATTAAAGCCCCTGAGTGTCTGTGGCAATGAATATTGCTGCTACC...ACA', SingleLetterAlphabet()), Seq('TGAGCACACTTTCAATTTGGGAGCTCTAGTACTACTATTTGCAACGCATGTATT...CAG', SingleLetterAlphabet()), Seq('AATTGAAATCTGACAGAGACCGTATAAGTTGTATTGAAAGACCCATCACGCGTA...CCG', SingleLetterAlphabet())]
but I need only nucleotide code :)

Comment: try `print s.seq`. With Seq object you can directly have the reverse complement, translation, etc... but if you don't want the object but just the string, use : `s.seq.tostring()`

Comment: Yes both print and s.seq.tostring() return only sequence but does it possible to save each sequences in the form of list elements (I need it for further processing) ?

Comment: Yes, just append s.seq.tostring in a new list. But it's actually already the case, my_sequences is a list of your sequences (plus others stuff). What do you wanna do ?

Comment: Yes, seq=[s.seq.tostring for s in allseq] also produced list consisted of many irrelevant information besides sequence. Also I've tried to make such list by means of numpy from your example and obtain error in this string                               my_sequences = allseq2[idsort]
for s in my_sequences:
    print s.seq                                               AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seq'

Comment: 1) You need parentheses after tostring : `seq=[s.seq.tostring() for s in allseq]` . 2) It works for me, detail a bit more what you wrote before.

Comment: Biopython works perfect ) 2- I dont know what with numpy- I just used your script with no changing and obtain error in the last str print s.seq AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seq

Comment: What is the content of `my_sequences[0]` ?